# How do I embed static text in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to embed static text, basically for a help file.  Something like

```
const help:String = "This is a help line.";
```

except for it would get it from a file?

```
const help:String = //retrieve text from a static file
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
public class EmbedText extends Sprite
{

    [Embed(source="textfile.txt",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    var myText:Class;

    public function EmbedText ()
    {           
        var txt:ByteArray = new myText() as ByteArray;
        trace(txt.toString());          
    }
}
```

This will include the file 'textfile.txt' into your SWF at compile-time. If you want to load the text-file from the server at run-time, you should instead use the URLLoader class.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a local field? Like so it can be accessed by filename, but without putting it in the Assets folder?